# How to create a square layout and set it center horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to customize a layout and make it into a square. In xml, I set the its layout_width and layout_height into 'match_parent'. And then in its onMeasure() method, I get the values of its height and width and set the shortest of them as the value of each side of square. The code is kind of like this:

```
<SquaredRelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>

public class SquaredRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        if(width > height) {
             super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else {
             super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Now here is my problem: I need to set this layout center horizontally of its parent. But every time when width > height, the layout will be aligned to left of its parent. Does any one how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:gravity="center"` in your `SquaredRelativeLayout`'s parent

or

use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your `SquaredRelativeLayout` (instead of `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`)

Comment: Actually, I wrap a FrameLayout for SquareLayout and set layout_gravity into center_horizonal, and finally that works. android:layout_centerInParent="true" is not working in my case.

Comment: I assumed you wrap it into another `RelativeLayout` (hence the `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` solution). If your wrapper is a `FrameLayout` (and with your approach on setting the gravity in the child), then you need to set `android:layout_gravity="center"` or `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"`. Setting it to center_horizontal is not enough, it is not going to look right in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use android:gravity="center" in your parent layout.